# Discord.py: not enough values to unpack when using around in channel.history()

Tags: python, datetime, discord, compiler-errors, discord.py

I am making a discord bot to get a random message from a discord server from around a certain time. Everything works, but when I use around in channel.history() it's giving me an error.

This is my code

```
    all_messages = []

    b = datetime(2023, 5, 18, 15, 17, 8, 132263)

    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=100, around=b):
            all_messages.append(message)

    message_to_send = random.choice(all_messages)
    while message_to_send == "":
        message_to_send = random.choice(all_messages)
    await ctx.send(message_to_send)
    await ctx.send(message_to_send.system_content)
```

This was the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\PycharmProjects\discordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\PycharmProjects\discordBot\main.py", line 63, in history
    async for message in channel.history(limit=100, around=b):
  File "\PycharmProjects\discordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1804, in history
    data, state, limit = await strategy(retrieve, state, limit)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the library. I recommend you combine the `before` and `after` parameters to get messages within a time/message range